# Why does my character not walk on the path when its on the correct axis

Tags: animation

[blend file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bI0e4TdFeO4cYByZfOrOnUYtgAHvnx_L)[video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uX2q2.jpg)

Ive had alot of problems with this model. Last time I was trying to connect the character to the path but it was glitching out because i connected it to the mesh and not the bones. Now i have connected it to the bones and when i press play it doesnt follow the path. I have tried changing the axis on the right hand side but it only not walks when its on the correct axis. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try to apply the rotation of your curve. If it doesn't work please share your file.

Comment: ok i added the blend file to the post. I cant figure it out. Thank You!

Comment: I don't see any link to the blend, only to the video

Comment: there is a link its at the top of the post. here is the link right here too https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bI0e4TdFeO4cYByZfOrOnUYtgAHvnx_L/view